# MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Столкнулся с MutationObserver, понадобилось прокинуть кнопку, по нажатию на которую, раскрывалось подменю с ссылками.

```
var target = document.querySelector('#head-menu');

var observer3 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log(mutation.type);
      if(mutation.target.id == 'main-menu-doc') {
          console.log(mutation);
      }
    });    
  });

   observer3.observe(target,  config);

   var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
```

Попробовал данный код, но выводит ошибку Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
Хотя-бы простенький пример увидеть, как это должно выглядеть(классы и прочее не важно). :[
upd.

```
$("#head-menu .container ul").append('<li class="main-menu-doc" id="main-menu-doc"><span><a href="#">Инструкция по заказам</a></span></li>');
```

Как закидывал кнопку.

Comment: observer3.observe(target,  config); а что такое target тут?

Comment: @AzizUmarov #head-menu, основной контейнер для меню

Comment: Добавьте код страницы частично чтоб можно было смотреть вместе

Comment: @AzizUmarov Если правильно понял, обновил вопрос. Добавил как прокидывал саму кнопку, по нажатию на которую, должно быть меню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой пример ок?

```js
// identify an element to observe
const elementToObserve = document.querySelector("#targetElementId");

// create a new instance of `MutationObserver` named `observer`, 
// passing it a callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    console.log('callback that runs when observer is triggered');
});

// call `observe()` on that MutationObserver instance, 
// passing it the element to observe, and the options object
observer.observe(elementToObserve, {subtree: true, childList: true});

function myFunction() {
  elementToObserve.innerText = "test ok";
}
```

```html
<div id="targetElementId">test</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```